# Como servir um frontend em vue.js/vue-cli na rede local e usá-lo por estações de trabalho que não possuem conexão com a internet?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express.js, redes, cliente-servidor

Preciso desenvolver uma aplicação web com o seguinte cenário:

- Servidor: hospeda a aplicação, tem conexão com a internet para se comunicar com as APIs;
- Estações: máquinas restritas, sem conexão a internet, usuários vão interagir com a aplicação hospedada no servidor

Meu atual experimento consiste em um frontend feito com vue.js/vue-cli, servido por um proxy (express.js) em node.js.

Tenho um desktop (que chamarei de servidor) e um note (que chamarei de estação de trabalho) conectados a mesma rede por um roteador wi-fi e já consegui fazer a "estação de trabalho" acessar a aplicação hospedada no "servidor", usando por exemplo, o endereço http://10.0.10.133:3000, 10.0.10.133 (ip do servidor) + 3000 (porta usada pelo proxy).

Minha pergunta é: a estação de trabalho realmente está operando o frontend sem uso da internet? Como posso me certificar disso? O que posso fazer pra simular a restrição de acesso a internet na estação de trabalho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro do Chrome, use o atalho Ctrl+Shift+J. Ao abrir o console de desenvolvedor, selecione a aba network e verifique nas listas de requisições se todas elas são feitas ao seu servidor local. Para ter mais informações sobre a requisição, você pode clicar nela.

Caso alguma requisição esteja sendo feita para outro host e seu status seja 200, a sua estação de trabalho está acessando recursos externos do seu servidor através da internet.

[image: Exemplo da lista de requisições]

Comment: Willian, obg pela ajuda. Verifiquei as requisições, todas são feitas para ip do “servidor” e funcionam. Isso já prova que a aplicação acessada pela estação não esta usando a internet? Pergunto isso pq não consigo restringir a internet na estação, cheguei a criar uma regra de saída no firewall do windows, bloqueando conexões do chrome, mas ao testar a aplicação na estação, todas as requisições falharam.

Comment: Acredito que sim! Se todas as requisições feitas vão para o "servidor", a estação não está se conectando com a internet para acessar a aplicação. Você só precisa garantir que a conexão entre a estação e o servidor seja feita através da rede local. Para melhorar a segurança desse sistema, seria melhor você utilizar um hub ou switch para conectar as estações no servidor, sem precisar de uma conexão com rede externa

Comment: @DiogoMarins você consegue bloquear a conexão externa por Rage de IP no seu Roteador, ou simplesmente colocar o Roteador para apontar única e exclusivamente para o seu Servidor, ou seja, ligar todos os Clientes a um Roteador que liga n servidor e não tem porta de saída da Rede, isso impedirá o acesso a internet e permitir apenas o servidor de ser acessado e a API irá funcionar pois as requisições do front serão feitas para o server e o server irá Rotear para fora e devolver, o cliente não poderá usar desta "artimanha" para acessar sites fora da API

Comment: flourigh, obg pela ajuda. Não tenho acesso ao sistema do roteador por este ser fornecido pela minha operadora de internet, como se fosse "blindado", só consigo fazer pouquíssimas coisas por um app mobile... De qualquer forma, sua resposta será usada futuramente.